# If $u\in H_0^1$ admits a weak Laplacian in $L^2$, are we able to show $\nabla u\in L^p$ for some $p>2$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, laplacian, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open

> Let $u\in H_0^1(\Lambda)$ admit a weak Laplacian $\Delta u\in L^2(\Lambda)$. Are we able to show that $$\nabla u\in L^p(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\tag1$$ for some $p>2$?

If

- $\partial\Lambda\in C^2$ or
- $\Lambda$ is convex,

then we can even show that $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$ and the desired conclusion is possible (for small $d$) by the *Sobolev inequality*. However, I wondered whether we can show the weaker result $(1)$ without one of these assumptions. It would be fine for me, if we assume

- $d\le 3$,
- $\Lambda$ is connected or
- $\partial\Lambda$ is Lipschitz

Comment: What did you get exactly for $d\le 3$ ?

Comment: By the Gagliardo-Niremberg interpolation inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) the supremum of the set of $p$s such that $\Delta u\in L^p$ should depend on $d$, too.

Comment: @user1952009 I'm $d\le3$, then $H_0^1(\Lambda)\subseteq L^6(\Lambda)$ by the Sobolev inequality. But that doesn't help. Maybe I've missed your point.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm sorry, but I think that I don't understand what you're telling me. I don't what that $\Delta u\in L^p(\Lambda)$ for some $p>2$. I want that $\Delta u\in L^2(\Lambda)$ implies $\nabla u\in L^p(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ for some (preferably large) $p>2$. In fact, I hope for $p=4$ at least in the case $d\le3$.